# Создание белого списка устройств wifi сети

Tags: сеть, администрирование, wifi, mikrotik, wlan

Можно ли создать некий white list, состоящий из MAC адрессов устройств, подключаемых к роутеру. И сделать так, что бы данных white list активировался в заданное время?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/mikrotik/thread2233907.html) про списки. По поводу временного доступа непонятно совсем.

Comment: От взлома это не поможет. Только от детей. Мак можно перехватить и подменить. Вариант хорош только для реализации родительского контроля.

Answer (score 0):

Снимай галочку "default autentificate" на интерфейсе вайфая. На вкладке Access List в окне Wireless заполняй список маков.

Расписание - можно. Time параметр есть в access list.

Отключить белый список по времени или временно можно добавив запись без мака.